# Deep copy of struct in C

Tags: c, struct, copy, memcpy

I have the following structs, and need to make a deep copy of state into newState.

```
typedef struct statestruct{
    int instrMem[100];
    IDTType ID;
    int cycles;
} stateType;

typedef struct ID{
    int val;
} IDType;
```

Assuming that state is already initialized, why doesn't the following code work? It appears that it is only doing a shallow copy, and I can't change the val inside newState without it changing in state.

```
newState = (stateType*)malloc(sizeof(stateType));
newState = state;
memcpy(&(newState->ID), &(state->ID), sizeof(IDType));
```

Comment: `newState = state;` --> memoriy leak, you want `*newState = *state;`

Comment: @KeineLust Please make that an answer, so that this gets out of the list of unanswered questions. You might check whether the memcpy line is necessary.

Comment: @Yunnosch, done, and yes, `memcpy` seems redundant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reserving space for the pointer in:

```
newState = (stateType*)malloc(sizeof(stateType)); /* Don't cast malloc */
```

but in the next line, you overwrite the address returned by `malloc` (memory leak):

```
newState = state;
```

If you want to copy the contents of where `state` points, just use:

```
newState = malloc(sizeof(stateType));
*newState = *state; /* Dereference to access the contents */
```

This line doesn't make sense:

```
memcpy(&(newState->ID), &(state->ID), sizeof(IDType));
```

because this member (`ID`) is already copied when you assign using `=`